# Remove SELECT options based on another SELECT selected in dynamic select dropdown

Tags: reactjs

```
const initData = [
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"Type A",
      "description":"Description Type A"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"Type B",
      "description":"Description Type B"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"Type C",
      "description":"Description Type C"
   }
]
const [listOption, setListOption] =  useState(initData);
const arr = ['James', 'Paul', 'John', 'George', 'Ringo'];

const Check = (e, i) => {
    e.preventDefault();
      setListOption(
        initData.filter((entry) => entry.id !== parseInt(e.target.value))
      );
  };
```

I have some selects dropdown like this.

```
{arr.map(item => (
       <select
       name="Type A"
       onChange={(e) => {
        Check(e);
       }}
     >
       {listOption &&
         listOption.map((x) => {
           return (
             <option value={x.id} key={"key" + x.id}>
               {x.name + item}
             </option>
           );
         })}
     </select>
      ))}
```

I want it so that when the user selects `"name":"Type A"` in the `first` Select dropdown, on another Selects dropdown user can only choose `"name":"Type B"`, `"name":"Type C"`.

Or if user selects `"name":"Type B"` in `second` or `third` Select dropdown, on another Selects dropdown user can only choose `"name":"Type A"`, `"name":"Type C"`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Your code does work, but will only filter out the selected option once. After changing the second input, the first option will be available again, right?

Answer (score 0):

It is better for you to have another array that will hold all selected options in that moment. So, you would dynamically change data in that array and you would compare your first array with selected options with the second array that holds the options that had been already selected and in other select dropdowns you would give particular options based on that comparison.